Why are we using Google Chrome version 128.0.6613.119 when the latest version is 130.0.6723.69?
I keep getting a message on my screen asking me to install the latest version of Chrome because my version cannot be updated.
Previously I installed Google Chrome by downloading it. Then the regular updates installed the Ubuntu version which took over the version I installed myself.
So which version should we installed? The one through the automatic updates or the one that we download and install ourselves.
Why is Ubuntu creating a problem by forcing an install of a version that cannot be updated and not accepting the Google Chrome latest version like it was in the past?
It's just annoying to go through an artificial problem that didn't exist until very recently.

Google Chrome's repository is maintained by Google, so ask them. Ubuntu does not package it, so I don't know where you're getting the idea that there is an Ubuntu version.

I installed the deb version myself but the Flatpak version went back in term of versions. I got few updates and today I started getting the message can't update Google Chrome "relaunch to update". It's very confusing as I don't know which is which.

Flatpak? Ubuntu doesn't maintain any Google Chrome Flatpak either. And neither does Google - they only provide debs and rpms. Ask whoever's maintaining this unofficial flatpak what's wrong with it

Try uninstalling it, downloading it again, and then installing the latest version.  That should solve your problem.  But don't bother complaining here about it -- as was already mentioned, it's not officially part of Ubuntu.  You will need to ask the people who maintain that package.

If you want a version of Chrome that Ubuntu does maintain, you can install the snap version of Chromium.

@ajgringo619, hwo do I get rid of the Flatpak?

flatpak uninstall com.google.Chrome should work. But before you do that, when did you update your flatpaks? According to https://flathub.org/apps/com.google.Chrome, it was updated to v130.0.6723.69-1 5 days ago.

I am a total ignorant when it comes to knowing what to do and about who does what. I will follow your advice. Thanks a bunch.

The correct way to install Chrome on Ubuntu is by downloading the .deb file from here and installing the .deb file. Its installer will create the necessary files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d so that apt can check Google repositories and update Chrome every time it updates the whole system.
You should uninstall any other Chrome installation before you install a new one.

That exactly what I did but the deb file wouldn't install. I find online the help to get it to install. I was happy with the latest version.But soon later, I ended up with two icons for Chrome and it went downward from them. I never selected the flatpack version myself.

I've found (but have not investigated why) that if you install the chrome deb file and then delete the sources file (or it gets disabled by do-release-upgrade) then it doesn't get reinstalled or re-enabled, even after purging and reinstalling the deb file.  Recreating the sources file (or obviously, reenabling it) fixes this, but that's a manual process.
